# margin-bottom / vertical space strategy for CSS columns (flex)

Tags: css, flexbox, margin

### Scenario

One section at the top with two columns (flex). Each column containing multiple elements.

One section below that with a single column.

The vertical space between elements within each column should be 30px (we are considering rem or em sizes, but let's stick to px for this discussion).

The vertical space between sections should be 40px. (I am choosing a different number here to make it more interesting.)

### Implementation, first attempt

The first step is to set `margin-bottom` on different elements.

```
<style>
.section-top {
  display: flex;
}
.section-top > div {
  width: 50%;
}
.container > section {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.column-left > section,
.column-right > section {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <section class="section-top">
    <!-- top section with two columns (flex) -->
    <div class="column-left">
      <section>Block L1</section>
      <section>Block L2</section>
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
      <section>Block R1</section>
      <section>Block R2</section>
      <section>Block R3</section>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section-bottom">Section 2</div>
  <section class="section-bottom">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

### Problem

Now there is 70px vertical space between the visible content of the top section and the lower sections. Instead, we only want 40px.

This is not surprising, it is known that vertical margin on flex items does not collapse with the margin of the container.

### Question

What is a good and common strategy to solve this, and only have 40px instead of 70px space between the top sections and the lower sections?

Ideally this should support:

- Different number and height of elements in each column.
- Possibility of a column with no elements.
- Different vertical spacing for column elements vs top-level sections.
- Neutralize or collapse with margins from nested elements.
- Component-based CSS, where the definition of the margin between top-level sections is independent of the section contents.

### What I tried so far

There are many ways to solve this technically:

- Set `margin-bottom: 0;` on `:last-child` in each column.

  - Problem: Does not neutralize margins from nested elements.
- Use `margin-bottom: 0;` on `.section-top`, and instead have the 40px in each column or on the last-child item inside each column.

  - Problem: Need to define the 40px in two places. E.g. if I want to change the vertical space between top-level sections to 60px later, I will also need to update the CSS for the columns.
- Use negative margins to compensate?

All of this will work, but perhaps there is something better out there which I am not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. I don't know if it is the best, but it works for me.

We add an `::after` pseudo-element into each column.

```
<style>
.container > section {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.section-top {
  display: flex;
}
.section-top > .column {
  width: 50%;
}
.section-top > .column > section {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.section-top > .column::after {
  /* Optionally change these to 40px / -40px, not sure what is better */
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <section class="section-top">
    <!-- top section with two columns (flex) -->
    <div class="column column-left">
      <section>Block L1</section>
      <section>Block L2</section>
    </div>
    <div class="column column-right">
      <section>Block R1</section>
      <section>Block R2</section>
      <section>Block R3</section>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section-bottom">Section 2</div>
  <section class="section-bottom">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a dead end. It removes the space between columns if they are stacked vertically on mobile.